# functional equation with improper integral

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, functional-equations, laurent-series

Given that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded.
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x-y)^2}f(y)dy=0, \forall x \in\mathbb{R} $
Prove that $f(x)=0, \forall x \in\mathbb{R}$

P/s: I tried to use complex analysis such as Laurent series, Fourier series but I could not prove it.
Please do not choose functions such as $\sin(x-y)$ as an counter-example, because you misunderstood the problem.

Comment: please help me to solve the problem @AaronHendrickson if you can , I tried using methods but I could not solve it

Comment: @AaronHendrickson noted that $f$ is a one-variable function and the function is fixed at first with such one variable. For example, if you choose $f(x)=\sin(x-y)$ and fix this function at first with one variable as $x$, then $f(y)=\sin(y-y)=0$

Comment: It's a convolution integral. See what you get when you Fourier transform it.

Comment: No sir @DisintegratingByParts . We do not know if f(x) meets the condition of Fourier transform

Comment: I posted something for you that should work.

Answer (score 3):

$$
   0= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2-y^2+2xy}f(x)dx \\= e^{-y^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{+2xy}e^{-x^2}f(x)dx,\;\; y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Now you can use Complex Analysis on the following entire function $F$ that vanishes on the real line:
$$
        F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2xz}e^{-x^2}f(x)dx = 0,\;\;\; z\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
The conclusion is that $F \equiv 0$ everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$, and in particular on the imaginary line, which is a Fourier transform of $e^{-x^2}f(x)$. The conclusion is that $f$ must vanish almost everywhere.

Comment: "F(z)=0 for all z belongs to R, implies that F(z)=0 for all z belongs to C". That is not a good point, sir. Can you explain more

Comment: @WgTTHT A holomorphic function on an open connected region of $\mathbb{C}$ which has a zero set that is infinite and has a cluster point in the region must be identically $0$.

Comment: I wonder if the condition "f is bounded" and "f is continuous" are necessary conditions? Can you make the problem stronger with weaker condition ?

Comment: @WgTTHT : The argument should work if you assume that $e^{x^2}f(x)$ is absolutely integrable, or something just a little stronger than that.

Comment: How can you know F is holomorphic?

Comment: @WgTTHT : $F$ is continuous, and if you integrate $F$ around any finite closed path in the plane, you can interchange orders of integration and get $0$. So it is holomorphic by Morera's Theorem. And you can know what the derivative is by a similar procedure using Cauchy's integral. Complex Analysis allows you to turn the more difficult problems of differentiation into integration.

Comment: please guide me to clear your point apply Morera's Theorem and interchange the orders of integration. Please noted the condition of interchange the orders of integration

Comment: please noted that condition of Cauchy's Integral is the function must be holomorphic. We cannot use Cauchy's Integral while we do not know the function if holomorphic or not?

Comment: if using your explanation of Morera's theorem, can I prove "every Fourier Transform can be differentiable?"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025789/show-that-the-fourier-transform-is-differentiable

Comment: I have read Morera's Theorem, but I do not how to ensure that we can use Fubini's Theorem to change the order of integration in this problem. Please help me to prove it

Comment: How can you know $F(z)$ is continuous? @disintegrating by parts

Comment: @WgTTHT : Dominated Convergence Theorem is one way.