# Differentiation of Fourier Transform using Morera's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

What is wrong with my proof?
Let Fourier transform of $f(x)$ exists and be $\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$
We will find the condition of $\frac{d}{d\omega}\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega)$ exists
If $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ exists then
Using Morera's theorem:
$\int_\gamma\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dxd\omega$=$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx\int_\gamma e^{-i\omega x}d\omega$=$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx\cdot 0$=$0$
Thus the condition of differentiation of Fourier transform is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ exists
However, according to 2 following results:

1. [Show that the Fourier Transform is differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025789/show-that-the-fourier-transform-is-differentiable)
2. [Derivative of Fourier transform: $F[f]'=F[-ixf(x)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032137/derivative-of-fourier-transform-ff-f-ixfx)
   We have the condition of differentiation of Fourier transform is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx$ exists
   Which is true?

Comment: To apply Morera's theorem to a function $F$, you need to be able to show that $F$ is continuous in some open connected region $\Omega$ of the complex plane, and you need to be able to show that all closed path integrals of $F$ in $\Omega$ are $0$.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem

Comment: Morera's Theorem does not apply to the real line as a region. It's not an open region in the complex plane.

Comment: Can we use Morera's Theorem to prove the condition of differentiation of Fourier transform as $xf(x)$ integrable?

Comment: not generally because the Fourier transform does not generally extend into the complex plane.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this idea to show that the Fourier transform is even holomorphic is that for Fubini's theorem you would need that $|f(x)e^{i\omega x}|$ is integrable in $\mathbb R\times \Omega$ for an open set $\Omega \subseteq\mathbb C$. You then have to estimate $$|e^{i\omega x}|=e^{\Re(i\omega x)} =e^{-\Im(\omega)x}.$$
Your idea works if $f$ has compact support. This case is treated in the Paley-Wiener-Schwartz theorem of distribution theory.